# Displaying multiple Rows and Columns in django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I'm using **django-crispy-forms** with Twitter Bootstrap , and I'm having some issues with customizing my forms into multiple rows and columns. One example problem is that nothing happens when I try to split the form into two columns:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Column('field1', 'field3'),
        Column('field2', 'field4'),
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Model
```

Looking at the html output, I see that there is the `<div class="formColumn">`, but the form is displayed in one single column. Maybe is this an css issue? I am using Bootstrap 2.1.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks maraujo.

I've achieved this using the div tag and the bootstrap docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div('field1', css_class='span6'),
            Div('field3', css_class='span6'),  
        css_class='row-fluid'), 
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Model
```

For bootstrap3 replace `span6` with `col-xs-6` http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Nice one, I will write this down in the docs for other people, it's a good practice.

Comment: @maraujop If I want an actual <table> which template should I override? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Crispy doesn't do table layouts, and neither should you. HTML table layouts have been deprecated for at least a decade now.

Comment: For bootstrap3 also replace 'row-fluid' with 'row'

Comment: For bootstrap4 see @pepjin answer below

Answer (score 18):

Small 2018 update on the answer by **martinpaulucci**:

For Bootstrap 4 and latest django-crispy-forms 1.7.2 use:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Field('field1', wrapper_class='col-md-3'),
            Field('field3', wrapper_class='col-md-9'),  
        css_class='form-row') 
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Model
```

The use of the Field tag in stead of the Div tag avoids another unnecessary wrapper div. To improve on that you can replace crispy-forms Row with your own if you're going to use more than one row:

```
class Row(Div):
    css_class = "form-row"
```

then use:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Row(
            Field('field1', wrapper_class='col-md-3'),
            Field('field3', wrapper_class='col-md-9')  
        ) 
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Model
```

Comment: Where does the overriding row class go?

Comment: You can put it somewere in the same file before your form class.

Answer (score 5):

June 2022 Update on the answer by **martinpaulucci** and **Pepijn**:
For Bootstrap 5 and django-crispy-forms 1.14.0, css_class = "form-row" no longer works. Instead use 'row':

```
class Row(Div):
    css_class = 'row'
```

Here's an example implementation using the Row class defined by **Pepijn** above (forms.py):

```
class Row(Div):
    css_class = 'row g-3'

class BlogUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    Create a custom user creation form using the custom BlogUser user model.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Field('username', wrapper_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                Field('email', wrapper_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
            ),
            'password1',
            'password2',
            Row(
                Field('first_name', wrapper_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                Field('last_name', wrapper_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
                Field('date_born', wrapper_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'),
            ),
            'short_bio',
            Submit('submit', 'Submit')
        )

    class Meta:
        model = BlogUser
        fields = ("username", 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_born', 'short_bio')
```

(I added 'g-3' to my css_class in the implementation to add gutters between the rows).

In case anyone is curious, in my settings.py the crispy_template_pack is still defined as bootstrap4 as per the [docs](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html); however, bootstrap5 still seems to work with django-crispy-forms so far as I've found.

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Answer (score 3):

Had issue with Django3 + ModelForm displaying multiple fields on the same row like this

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SupplierDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Row(
            Column('nom', css_class='form-group col-2 mb-0'),
            Column('email', css_class='form-group col-4 mb-0'),
        )
    )
```

I noticed that Crispy "row" class is in fact a "form-row" class that doesn't match with Bootstrap 4 classes.

**Pepijn's** tip did the job. Thanks

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30069869)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Awesome, thanks.